# FastAPI create a generic response model that would suit requirements

Tags: python, rest, fastapi

I've been working with FastAPI for some time, it's a great framework.
However real life scenarios can be surprising, sometimes a non-standard approach is necessary. There's a one case I'd like to ask your help with.

There's a strange external requirement that a model response should be formatted as stated in example:

**Desired behavior:**

`GET /object/1`

```
{status: ‘success’, data: {object: {id:‘1’, category: ‘test’ …}}}
```

`GET /objects`

```
{status: ‘success’, data: {objects: [...]}}}
```

**Current behavior:**

GET `/object/1` would respond:

```
{id: 1,field1:"content",... }
```

GET `/objects/` would send a List of Object e.g.,:

```
{
 [
   {id: 1,field1:"content",... },
   {id: 1,field1:"content",... },
    ...
 ]
}
```

*You can substitute 'object' by any class, it's just for description purposes.*

**How to write a generic response model that will suit those reqs?**

I know I can produce response model that would contain `status:str` and (depending on class) data structure e.g `ticket:Ticket` or `tickets:List[Ticket]`.

**The point is there's a number of classes so I hope there's a more pythonic way to do it.**

**Thanks for help.**

Comment: How much of the structure of the response do you want to avoid leaking into the implementation? i.e. are you happy with returning something like `{'data': {'objects': ...}}` from your endpoint as long as the response model is properly document, or do you want to automagically wrap returning a list inside the `objects` property? (i.e. do you want to do the wrapping automagically from what the API returns today by changing the response model?)

Comment: Well the thing is to make it generic in the way it would "automagically" detect what is the class, its type and produce the required response.
Actually I'm thinking maybe adding a middleware to modify original api response would be a good idea.

Comment: I'm guessing you also want that change reflected in the OpenAPI documentation? (i.e. FastAPI actually has to know about the expected change, and not just transform it in a middleware)

Comment: To be clear, the `object` key is actually supposed to be something different for every endpoint? Meaning the `data` key in the response for `/object/1` should map to `{"object": ...}`, but for `/foo/1` it should map to `{"foo": ...}`? That would be a strange requirement because (for one thing) the plural is impossible to encode in some generic way. But I just want to clarify. Or will it always be `{"object":  {...}}` and `{"objects": [...]}`?

Comment: Because making the response model generic to "detect" the class used is not the issue. That can be done. The problem is, if you want to somehow automatically set the attribute/field name (instead of `object`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Generic model with static field name

A **generic** model is a model where one field (or multiple) are annotated with a type variable. Thus the *type* of that field is unspecified by default and must be specified explicitly during subclassing and/or initialization. But that field is still just an attribute and an attribute must have a name. A **fixed** name.

To go from your example, say that is your model:

```json
{
  "status": "...",
  "data": {
    "object": {...}  # type variable
  }
}
```

Then we could define that model as generic *in terms of* the type of its `object` attribute.

This can be done using Pydantic's [`GenericModel`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#generic-models) like this:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel

M = TypeVar("M", bound=BaseModel)


class GenericSingleObject(GenericModel, Generic[M]):
    object: M


class GenericMultipleObjects(GenericModel, Generic[M]):
    objects: list[M]


class BaseGenericResponse(GenericModel):
    status: str


class GenericSingleResponse(BaseGenericResponse, Generic[M]):
    data: GenericSingleObject[M]


class GenericMultipleResponse(BaseGenericResponse, Generic[M]):
    data: GenericMultipleObjects[M]


class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: int


class Bar(BaseModel):
    x: float
```

As you can see, `GenericSingleObject` reflects the generic type we want for `data`, whereas `GenericSingleResponse` is generic in terms of the type parameter `M` of `GenericSingleObject`, which is the type of its `data` attribute.

If we now want to use one of our generic response models, we would need to specify it with a type argument (a concrete model) first, e.g. `GenericSingleResponse[Foo]`.

FastAPI deals with this just fine and can generate the correct OpenAPI documentation. The JSON schema for `GenericSingleResponse[Foo]` looks like this:

```json
{
    "title": "GenericSingleResponse[Foo]",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "status": {
            "title": "Status",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "data": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/GenericSingleObject_Foo_"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "status",
        "data"
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "Foo": {
            "title": "Foo",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "a": {
                    "title": "A",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "b": {
                    "title": "B",
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "a",
                "b"
            ]
        },
        "GenericSingleObject_Foo_": {
            "title": "GenericSingleObject[Foo]",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "object": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "object"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

To demonstrate it with FastAPI:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/foo/", response_model=GenericSingleResponse[Foo])
async def get_one_foo() -> dict[str, object]:
    return {"status": "foo", "data": {"object": {"a": "spam", "b": 123}}}
```

Sending a request to that route returns the following:

```json
{
  "status": "foo",
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "a": "spam",
      "b": 123
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Dynamically created model

If you *actually* want the attribute **name** to also be different every time, that is obviously no longer possible with static type annotations. In that case we would have to resort to actually creating the model type dynamically via [`pydantic.create_model`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation).

In that case there is really no point in genericity anymore because type safety is out of the window anyway, at least for the `data` model. We still have the option to define a `GenericResponse` model, which we can specify via our dynamically generated models, but this will make every static type checker mad, since we'll be using variables for types. Still, it might make for otherwise concise code.

We just need to define an algorithm for deriving the model parameters:

```py
from typing import Any, Generic, Optional, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel

M = TypeVar("M", bound=BaseModel)


def create_data_model(
    model: type[BaseModel],
    plural: bool = False,
    custom_plural_name: Optional[str] = None,
    **kwargs: Any,
) -> type[BaseModel]:
    data_field_name = model.__name__.lower()
    if plural:
        model_name = f"Multiple{model.__name__}"
        if custom_plural_name:
            data_field_name = custom_plural_name
        else:
            data_field_name += "s"
        kwargs[data_field_name] = (list[model], ...)  # type: ignore[valid-type]
    else:
        model_name = f"Single{model.__name__}"
        kwargs[data_field_name] = (model, ...)
    return create_model(model_name, **kwargs)


class GenericResponse(GenericModel, Generic[M]):
    status: str
    data: M
```

Using the same `Foo` and `Bar` examples as before:

```py
class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: int


class Bar(BaseModel):
    x: float


SingleFoo = create_data_model(Foo)
MultipleBar = create_data_model(Bar, plural=True)
```

This also works as expected with FastAPI including the automatically generated schemas/documentations:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/foo/", response_model=GenericResponse[SingleFoo])  # type: ignore[valid-type]
async def get_one_foo() -> dict[str, object]:
    return {"status": "foo", "data": {"foo": {"a": "spam", "b": 123}}}


@app.get("/bars/", response_model=GenericResponse[MultipleBar])  # type: ignore[valid-type]
async def get_multiple_bars() -> dict[str, object]:
    return {"status": "bars", "data": {"bars": [{"x": 3.14}, {"x": 0}]}}
```

Output is essentially the same as with the first approach.

You'll have to see, which one works better for you. I find the second option very strange because of the dynamic key/field name. But maybe that is what you need for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the exhausting answer and time you spent for typing samples.
I've used the `create_model` approach, despite is less self-explanatory  :)